# CRM 2011 ONLINE - Clone existing instance

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

Is it possible to clone an existing online instance (data + schema) into a new online instance? Client wants to keep both instances going.

Keep in mind this is a CRM 2011 online instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving your schema is straightforward: Export your solution from the existing organisation (instance), then import it into the new one. Once you publish it in the new org, your custom entities, forms, views etc will all be visible. (As an aside: This is a good way to backup your changes as you go, too)

Data, however, is different: Microsoft provide no tools to do this automatically.

You *may* be able to get help directly from Microsoft (or your Microsoft partner) with doing this, but my gut feel is that they won't be in a rush to help you out. If you don't have significant volumes of data, or if it's simple, the built-in export/import tools may help but you'll need to be smart about import ordering to ensure relationships etc stay intact.

Comment: Rossp, you are correct. As far as importing data, here are the 2 options I think are available:
1. Backup/Restore Microsoft online instance (only through Microsoft support). Not sure it can be done.
2. Obtain a backup of your online instance and migrate it to a temporary on premise instance. 
a. Perform any data clean required.
b. Create a new empty online instance.
c. Using Scribe or similar product, import existing data into new online instance.
d. Delete on premise instance.

Comment: How big is your database? You might be able to pull pertinent details out of the Online instance using Scribe, into either an on-premise instance or another Online organisation.